# Can blender import collada files with external references?

Tags: import, collada

I am trying to import a .dae collada file that contains external references in the form of:

```
<visual_scene id="Scene" name="Scene">
        <instance_node url="./trees.dae#appletree-0" />
</visual_scene>
```

The referenced file lives in the same directory as the referring file.
When I import the .dae I see no errors on the console.
Yet, no new geometry shows up in blender.

Are external references broken for Blender [as they seem to be for many Collada readers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14526624/301166)?

I tried with Blender version 2.76b

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Blender can indeed load geometry from external references.

I had bungled the test, because my referenced file was missing the tag:

`<library_nodes>
   ...
</library_nodes>`

Once I put those in, Blender did a great job of loading external references from Collada. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the syntax for external references in collada?  It would be very appreciated.